# What kinds of grape vines will grow in northeastern Turkey's cold climate?

Tags: plant-recommendations, fruits, grape-vine, climate

What kind of grape vines could grow in a cold climate, 4 months winter, temperatures of -20 °C, altitude 1000m. In Northeast Turkey climate is not compatible with grape vines that we know.

Comment: Should be plenty - that's only -4F and we regularly get -20F here and grow grapes of various sorts. You might start with New York State as one information source where grapes are grown in similar temperatures, but should ultimately seek out information sources closer to where you are trying to grow them... http://www.fruit.cornell.edu/grape/  And for much colder, Minnesota: http://www.grapes.umn.edu

Answer (score 2):

For native species, some of your best bets will be Cabernet Sauvignon, Cabernet Franc, and Limberger. I'm not sure if you can legally grow American/American-European cross grapes in Turkey, but if you can, just about all of those will be hardy in your area. Especially the American ones. They also have a faster ripening time.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to check out North American varieties. user145278, a bonus may be that if you are interested in using the leaves for stuffed vine leaves, the North American varieties have shallower lobes, and make for much easier rolling than the standard ME varieties!